# How do we secure Swagger UI with Windows Authentication .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-3.1, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I Expect
[image]

And I have referenced at the link: [How do we secure Swagger UI with Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62454751/how-do-we-secure-swagger-ui-with-windows-authentication) but it not show popup [image]

**My Code In Startup.cs**

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization(); 
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
        app.UseMiddleware<SwaggerAuthorizationMiddleware>();
        app.UseSwagger();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
            // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API cho dự án Trà Sữa Ji Ji");
            });
        }
        else
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API cho dự án Trà Sữa Ji Ji");
            });

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

    }
```

And My Code in **SwaggerAuthorizationMiddleware**

```
public class SwaggerAuthorizationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public SwaggerAuthorizationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<SwaggerAuthorizationMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // If API documentation route and user isn't authenticated or doesn't have the appropriate authorization, then block
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/swagger") && !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning($"API documentation endpoint unauthorized access attempt by [{context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress}]");
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
            return;
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```